# Copy data from one excel sheet to another (complex) using VBA based on column name

Tags: vba, excel, header

I'm very new to VBA and after 5 hours of watching videos and Googling, I think this is just too over my head... any help is very much appreciated.

So I have 2 excel worksheets: Sheet1 and Sheet2.  I have a Y/N column in Sheet1 and if the column = "Y" then I want to copy all the data from that row that has a matching column name in Sheet2.

```
Sheet1
Product     Price     SalesPerson    Date    Commission     Y/N
  A          $25         John       1/9/15      $3           Y 
  B          $20         John       1/12/15     $2           N  
  B          $15         Brad       1/5/15      $1           Y

Sheet2
Price     Product     Date     Salesperson
```

So for every time Y/N = Y then copy the data that matches over to sheet2 and do this until sheet1.col1 is null (looping).  The result would be this:

```
Sheet2
Price     Product     Date     Salesperson
 $25         A       1/9/15        John
 $15         B       1/5/15        Brad
```

The columns are not in order and are far too numerous to manually input. Then last but not least the Y/N column would need to clear upon finish.  I have tried to alter this with no luck:

```
Sub CopyHeaders()
Dim header As Range, headers As Range
Set headers = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1")

For Each header In headers
    If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) > 0 Then
        Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value)).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next
End Sub

Function GetHeaderColumn(header As String) As Integer
Dim headers As Range
Set headers = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:Z1")
GetHeaderColumn = IIf(IsNumeric(Application.Match(header, headers, 0)), Application.Match(header, headers, 0), 0)
End Function
```

This was designed to do something different than what I'm trying to do and I don't think I'm capable of changing this to work for me. How wold I do this?

Comment: I'm going to do some more research and will update this, but I was not able to get this code to work... probably due to sheet2 containing columns that are not in sheet1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When researching this further I was looking into creating a static array for the headers... then user3561813 provided this gem (I altered it slightly for my if statement and to loop through the sheet:

```
Sub validatetickets()

Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
If Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 43) = "Y" Then

Dim wsOrigin As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim nCopyRow As Long
Dim nPasteRow As Long
Dim rngFnd As Range
Dim rngDestSearch As Range
Dim cel As Range

Const ORIGIN_ROW_HEADERS = 1
Const DEST_ROW_HEADERS = 1


Set wsOrigin = Sheets("Case")
Set wsDest = Sheets("Sheet1")

nCopyRow = ActiveCell.Row
nPasteRow = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Set rngDestSearch = Intersect(wsDest.UsedRange, wsDest.Rows(DEST_ROW_HEADERS))

For Each cel In Intersect(wsOrigin.UsedRange, wsOrigin.Rows(ORIGIN_ROW_HEADERS))
On Error Resume Next
    Set rngFnd = rngDestSearch.Find(cel.Value)

    If rngFnd Is Nothing Then
        'Do Nothing as Header Does not Exist
    Else
        wsDest.Cells(nPasteRow, rngFnd.Column).Value = wsOrigin.Cells(nCopyRow, cel.Column).Value
    End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set rngFnd = Nothing
Next cel
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Else: ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If

Loop
End Sub
```

This is pretty slick the way it works and is very scalable.  Doesn't depend on both sheets having identical columns etc...  I can see this being very useful in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, now it works also if you have columns in Sheet2 that do not exist in Sheet1.

Sub CopySheet()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim Search As String
    Dim Column As Integer

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
'Sets an Autofilter to sort out only your Yes rows.
Selection.Autofilter
'Change Field:=5 to the number of the column with your Y/N.
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$1:$G$3").Autofilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Y"

'Finds the last row
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

i = 1
'Change the 3 to the number of columns you got in Sheet2
Do While i <= 3
    Search = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, i).Value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    'Update the Range to cover all your Columns in Sheet1.
    If IsError(Application.Match(Search, Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:G1"), 0)) Then
        'nothing
    Else
        Column = Application.Match(Search, Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:G1"), 0)
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, Column).Resize(LastRow, 1).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, i).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

'Clear all Y/N = Y
'Update the Range to cover all your Columns in Sheet1.
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Column = Application.Match("Y/N", Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:G1"), 0)
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, Column).Resize(LastRow, 1).Select
Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: So my sheet2 does have columns that are not in sheet1 :(

Comment: Changed it to work even if there are columns in sheet2 that does not exist in sheet1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also, provided that the columns are as you mentioned above (A to F in sheet1 and A to D in sheet2).

```
Sub copies()
    Dim i, j, row As Integer
    j = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).row
    For i = 1 To j
        If Cells(i, 6) = "Y" Then _
        row = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1").End(xlDown).row + 1
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(row, 1) = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 2)
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(row, 2) = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(row, 3) = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 4)
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(row, 4) = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 3)
    Next
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("F:F").ClearContents
End Sub
```