# Copy Data in some other sheet based on search Criteria and also follow matching rule or procedure

Tags: vba, excel

I have sheet that contains Data from (A10: I37). I want to sort Data based on specific word in Column A. In My case it is **Yes** and then I want to copy the Data in front of the word **Yes** to some other **sheet 2** but I want the data to be assigned in front of their specific words like Info 1 Info 2 Info 3.    **I want my data to be copied to sheet2 based on search criteria like Yes and under their respective words assigned in Row 10.** I have tried to write something but still I am unable to approach what I want. Any guidance will be appreciated.

Let’s make it simple.

```
         **Sheet1**                              **Sheet 2**
 10 Col A    Info 1   Info 2   Info 3   Info 4                                      

    Yes       Car      Bus     Plane    Truck    Info 1   Car   1  Bat  tall      

    No        1         2       3         4      Info 2   Bus   2  Pen   5
    Yes      bat       pen      copy     ball    Info 3   Plane 3  copy  6   
    No       tall       5       6         7      Info 4   truck 4  ball  7
```

**Code**

```
       Dim i As Integer
       Dim Percent As Variant
       Dim Search As String
       Search = InputBox("Enter your search word here")
       If Search = "" Then Exit Sub
       For i = 1 To Range("A65536").Cells.End(xlUp).Row
           If Cells(i, 1) = Search Then GoTo Other
         Next i
               MsgBox "Nicht in Spalte enthalten"
          Exit Sub
       Other:
         For i = 1 To Range("A65536").Cells.End(xlUp).Row
          If Cells(i, 1) = Search Then
            Cells(i, 2).Select
             'Range("B17").Select
            Selection.Copy
             'Range("K18").Select
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C16") 


          End If
          Next i
```

**Code 2**
This code I found from somewhere tried to modify it as par my demand but but till unable to mold it.

```
Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

' Change worksheet designations as needed
Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

j = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
For Each c In Source.Range("A1:A1000")   ' Do 1000 rows
    If c = "yes" Then
     Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)


       j = j + 1
    End If
Next c
```

This code only searches for Yes word and copy the whole row into sheet 2 but I want to data to be copied in next sheet based on matching criteria .

**Any help would be appreciated as I have tried but remained unable to find a way. Thanks.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the relationship between `Info 1` and `ball` in your example?

Comment: Info 4 contains Truck, 4, Ball,   7 .
          Info 1 contains    Car, 1  , Bat , tall etc. 
Info means Information and Info 1 means it contains data that is related to it like Car,1,Bat, Tall

Comment: There is no relation between Info 1 and ball. There is relation between Info 4 and ball.

Comment: Sorry - what I meant is - what is the relationship between `Info 4` and `ball` (not `Info 1`). Because `ball` is on a `Yes` row. And, it is on the `Info 4` row on `Sheet` in your example.

Comment: Please have a look at picture above. It will make it easy . Info 4 has data and ball comes under info 4 . Yes is only search criteria . I can change position of yes also.

Comment: Actually Ball comes under Info 4 and Yes is only search criteria means whenever our code will find Yes in Col A it copies the data next to that row into sheet 2 but under the same category like Info1 ,2,3,4.

Comment: In second Picture I have erased No so code will search for yes and performs the copy action.

Comment: anyone who has idea ...

Comment: This question has been asked again here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43173398/data-filtering-based-on-specific-word-and-then-copy-it-to-next-sheet-based-on-ma

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038263/copy-data-from-one-excel-sheet-to-another-complex-using-vba-based-on-column-na

Comment: The above link is the same question that is asked by some guy and my question is a little bit related to it . I just want to copy the transpose of data except the column containing Yes/NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify the second macro that you found to consider the cell instead of a range and transpose the copied range in the target sheet:

```
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim j As Integer
 Dim Source As Worksheet
 Dim Target As Worksheet

 ' Change worksheet designations as needed
 Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

 Rows(1).Select.Copy 
 Target.Cells(1,1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

 j = 2     ' Start copying to column 2 in target sheet
 i = 1     ' Start Searching from the first row in source sheet

 While Source.Cells(i,1) <> ""

    If Source.Cells(i,1) = "yes" Then
       Rows(i).Select.Copy 
       Target.Cells(1,j).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
       j = j + 1
    End If

    i = i + 1
 Wend
```

Comment: Thx Masoud but this code only copies the rows containing Yes . What I want is to copy the transpose of data of Rows containing yes to other sheet in their respective place.

Comment: @MuhammadNauman Please add this to yoir question as desired output and try to be clear by providing a picture. I will modify my answer when I got some time.

Comment: @MuhammadNauman I quote this: "Don't forget to tip your waiter by clicking on the check mark next to the answer if that is useful." This will let everyone to find the answer to an already asked question.

Comment: sorry for delayed reply . As i was not available . Thanks a lot for all the help and your time. I really appreciate it . It worked great for me and keep doing help for oters.Sorry again for delay.